# How can I call ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener programmatically?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I'm trying to change the color of the tab icons in my TabLayout, actually I achived this using addOnTabSelectedListener, but this only works when I swipe between tabs. So I wanna that the icon color of the first tab be the same that the color when you change tab.

I tried with  viewPager.setCurrentItem(), but this only work when the index passed is diferent that 0 (the first tab).

So, How can I call ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener programmatically?

This is my code:

```
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
            super.onTabReselected(tab);
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.prehipertension);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
            super.onTabUnselected(tab);
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.blancoTransparencia);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.blanco);
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    });

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

This is the app when Run it for fist time.
[image: tablayout]

When swipe to the second tab (and back to the first tab), the icon color change properly.

[image: tablayout icon]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i don't know i could understand your problem correctly or not but i worked with pager view and handle it's processes by this algorithm. (check it maybe you found what you want).

1- Firstly you identify your tabs.

```
private void createTabIcons(){
    // i get custom tab view.
    View profileTab = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null); 
    // set it's views such as its text and icon
    ViewAppHolder.CustomTabViewHolder customTabProfileViewHolder =
            new ViewAppHolder.CustomTabViewHolder(profileTab);
     // set properties of icon ... note this is my main tab so i set 'color.active'
    customTabProfileViewHolder.TAB_IMAGE_VIEW
            .setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp));
    customTabProfileViewHolder.TAB_IMAGE_VIEW
            .setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.active_tab));

    tabLayout.getTabAt(Constants.USER_PROFILE_TAB).setCustomView(profileTab);
    // it's the next tab by the same previous steps
    View friendsTab = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null);

    ViewAppHolder.CustomTabViewHolder customTabFriendsViewHolder =
            new ViewAppHolder.CustomTabViewHolder(friendsTab);
    // the diff is here .. i set the color of icon 'color.non_active'
    customTabFriendsViewHolder.TAB_IMAGE_VIEW
            .setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_group_black_24dp));
    customTabFriendsViewHolder.TAB_IMAGE_VIEW
            .setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.non_active_tab));

/// .... and remain tabs also have the same thing with color non_active.
```

2- then in both `onTabSelected` and `onTabUnselected` i just call method called `setCurrentTab()` and it's implement is that

```
private void setCurrentTab() {
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        int currentPosition = tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
        int unSelectedTabs = currentPosition;

        do {
            unSelectedTabs = (unSelectedTabs + 1) % 4;

            Log.e("un selected ", String.valueOf(unSelectedTabs));
            Log.e("un selected ", String.valueOf(currentPosition));

            ViewAppHolder.CustomTabViewHolder customTabViewHolder =
                    new ViewAppHolder.CustomTabViewHolder(
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(unSelectedTabs).getCustomView()
                    );


            if (unSelectedTabs != currentPosition) {
                customTabViewHolder.TAB_IMAGE_VIEW
                        .setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.non_active_tab));
            } else {
                customTabViewHolder.TAB_IMAGE_VIEW
                        .setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.active_tab));
            }

        } while (unSelectedTabs != currentPosition);
    }
}
```